# use get() and eval() to pass argument in dplyr functions

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I'm trying to write my function and need to pass argument inside.
Use mtcars dataset as an example:

```
get.param <- function(data, var){
    data %>% select(eval(var)) %>% 
             head()
}
get.param(mtcars, 'hp')
```

In the above function, replacing eval() with get() gave me error.
I'm little bit confused which one should I use. I use get() i some other functions and work.  What is the difference between these two?

Comment: What (choose >=1) is your second argument to your `get.param` intended to be: a literal string (as in your example); something that evaluates to a string (eg a variable with a string value); a name to be evaluated in the context of the first argument?

Comment: @zesla, please consider choosing an answer from one (click on check mark) that helped. This lets the community know the answer worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it to work via

```
get.param <- function(data, var){
    var <- enquo(var)
    data %>% select(!!var) %>% 
             head()
}
get.param(mtcars, hp)

                   hp
Mazda RX4         110
Mazda RX4 Wag     110
Datsun 710         93
Hornet 4 Drive    110
Hornet Sportabout 175
Valiant           105
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally one does not use `get` or `eval` with dplyr.  See the vignette in the rlang package for how it is done with that package; however, in this particular case one can just pass `var` directly to `select` adding parentheses around it so that it does not confuse it with a column called `"var"` should it exist.  If you are not worried about that edge case you could omit the parentheses.

```
get.param <- function(data, var) {
    data %>% select((var)) %>% head
}

get.param(mtcars, 'hp')
```

giving:

```
                   hp
Mazda RX4         110
Mazda RX4 Wag     110
Datsun 710         93
Hornet 4 Drive    110
Hornet Sportabout 175
Valiant           105
```

Another possibility is to use `...` like this and giving the same answer.  In this variation we don't need to add the parentheses to eliminate an edge case.  It also allows multiple columns to be specified.

```
get.param <- function(data, ...) {
    data %>% select(...) %>% head
}

get.param(mtcars, 'hp')
```

Comment: Good point. Have changed it to `(var)` to avoid that edge case.

Comment: I still think `get.param = function(data, var){head(data[,var,drop=FALSE])}` is less slippery (and 50x faster) but hey pipes and dplyr all the things.

Comment: But the question is how to use dplyr.

Comment: And if someone asked how to bash a nail in using a screwdriver would you not suggest they use a hammer instead?